# Ĉu "pluvi" povas havi subjekton aŭ objekton?

Tags: verbs

Mi pensas, ke oni ofte oni simple uzas "pluvas" sole, eble kun aldona adverbo. Sed ĉu eblus meti subjekton aŭ objekton al tiu verbo?

Por subjekto, ĉu eblus diri ekzemple "la ĉielo pluvas" aŭ "la nuboj pluvas"? Sekve, mi pensas... se ĝustas diri "Pluvas sango", "sango pluvas" ankaŭ devas ankaŭ ĝusti. Alternative la pluveroj estu objekto, kaj la frazo efektive estu "Pluvas sangon".

La sama afero demandeblas por "neĝi".

Answer (score 6):

La (kutime sensubjektaj) verboj de vetero povas kiel subjekton alpreni la specifan aĵon, kiu manifestiĝas, precipe, kiam estas metafora uzo:

*Sango pluvas* - *Polvo neĝas* ktp., kp. http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj_frazroloj/sensubjektaj.html

[Mi ne tute certas pri la severa nekapablo (laŭ PMEG) alpreni objekton, ĉar tipologie tiaj t.n. "internaj komplementoj", kiuj montras la specifan manifestiĝon de la ago (ekz. *iri longan vojon*), estas tute kutimaj.
(Redakto: Tamen PMEG verŝajne pravas, kp. la komentojn)]

Ĉiuokaze, miaopinie via ekzemplo "la ĉielo pluvas" ne funkcias, ĉar ĉielo ne estas tio, kio estas la pluvo, sed la deirpunkto aŭ la kaŭzanto de la pluvo, do efektive oni devus diri *la ĉielo pluvigas*, se oni volas tion esprimi.

Comment: Komentoj ne pluvas sur tiu respondo, do mi pluvigos unu: mi konsentas kun via respondo, sed vere mi ne kapablas imagi, kiaspeca rolanto povus alpreni objektan akuzativon kun _pluvi._ Se tio, kio falas (evtle. metafore) estas la subjekto, kio restas? Lokoj tipe havas prepoziciojn: _en la tuta regiono, sur la urbo, sub plumba ĉielo..._ Tempoj havas neobjektan (nepasivigeblan) akuzativon, kiu ne koncernas nin ĉi tie: _la tutan tagon_ (kp. la eblan _irata vojo_). Vi esprimis dubon, sed ne metis ekzemplon, do verŝajne ankaŭ vi ne povis trovi...

Comment: Mi pensis pri analogio al _iri longan vojon_, _kanti belan kanton_ - do, penseble!, _pluvi fortan pluvon_ (tio estas veraj objektoj, ne adjektoj kiel _la tutan tagon_). Tia akuzativo esprimas la temon de la ago, kiu kutime estas en la (netransitiva) verbo mem. Eble ĉi tie estas alie, ĉar _iri, kanti_ ktp. havas jam aganton kiel unuan komplementon, dum sensubjektaj verboj havas liberan lokon por nominativo, tiel ke la temo povas iĝi subjekto anstataŭ objekto. Jes, verŝajne estas tiel, do mi prilaboru mian respondon laŭe.

Comment: Nu, ĉar jam _forta pluvo pluvas,_ ĝi ne povas samtempe _esti pluvata._ Mi konsentas: aldona “interna rolanto” alprenas la unuan liberan lokon: akuzativon ĉe _iri_ (kiu normale havas jam unu nominativan rolanton), nominativon ĉe _pluvi_ (kiu normale havas nul rolantojn).

Comment: La kondiĉo de la uzado de la objekto ne estas klara en la respondo

Comment: Jes, sed el la diskuto ja evidentiĝis, ke oni tamen ne uzu objekton kun tiuj verboj. Mi ne tute viŝis la alineon pro tio, por ke oni povu kompreni la komentojn. Mi eble enkrampigu ĝin.

Answer (score 1):

La ĉielo pluvas = la ĉielo falas.

- ĉiaj benoj pluvas.
- la monpunoj pluvas.
- la akvo pluvas.
- sango pluvas.

Comment: "Pluvi = aferoj, kiujn fali." bv. nepre korekti tiun frazon, kiu tiel nek enhave nek gramatike havas sencon. - Kiel mi supre skribis, sub certaj kondioj preksa iuj netransitiva verbo povas tamen havi objekton.